# External Tool Configuration build options tab in Eclipse > Luna (i.e. Mars)

Tags: eclipse, less

I had a supercool hook set up on Eclipse to compile my project's `.css` theme file from its `.less` modules every time a `.less` module was modified by monitoring those resources through an "external tool configuration".

I could select which resources to monitor for triggering the nodejs less compiler tool on the `launch configurations` `build options` tab.

On eclipse Mars there is no such tab.

It really bothers me to loose this automation. Does anybody know where did that tab go or how can I keep this functionality without it?

[image]

Comment: This hasn't changed between Luna and Mars. Where exactly are you looking for this?

Comment: Well you are absolutely right. I was looking for it in the wrong place ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up such custom builders via the project's Properties dialog. Open the properties, then select the Builders section. There you can use the **New...** button to configure a Program to run as a builder.

[image]

[image]